# Best way to consume http resource from EJB or Java EE webapp

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpclient, ejb-3.0

I have a java ee 7 app with jsf2, ejb3.1 , jpa etc. running in a Glassfish4 container.

At the submission of a facelet, I want to call an external http resource (most probably using apache http client). The response is going to be text response, which I will need to parse and then do some db stuff afterwards as well.

My First idea is to call it from an ejb, but as the clint may spawn threads, it is not a good idea. I have also heard about ways to restrict the httpClient in such a way that it doesn't spawn threads e.g. use  HttpConnectionManager, don't use timeouts etc. But then I think I would loose some performance.

What about an asynchronous ejb method which can eventually use / trigger the httpClient ?

What will be the best way to achieve this?

What should I do to manage the connections ?

Comment: Are you trying to consume a resource? Or call some method? Your details are a bit sparse.

Comment: I am trying to get plain/text response from another server which I call using https. After parsing the response, I will need to extract data and update some db tables.

Comment: I don't see why you can't consume the site with `HttpClient` within the business code of your submit (may it be an EJB or CDI bean). If it's a question of taking too long and thus disturbing the user after submitting, I would delegate it to a background job (e.g. Asynchronous EJB).

Comment: @Geziefer ,  This is exactly what I have thought to implement. The issue with this is in every call of the ejb, I will create a connection and close it. And I would not be able to use the httpClient timeout functionality as it creates threads. I want to  explore some better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using a JAX-RS client as in this simple example:

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
 String content = client.target("http://www.google.de")
      .request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      .get(String.class);
```

More informations in the [Java EE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client001.htm).

Comment: Actually I am not much familiar with it.  Can it handle custom client security with a cert chain and private key ?

Comment: You have several possibilities to secure client communication - check out the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4722), which is the reference implementaion of JAX-RS.